# request.get returns 400 response when looping -- even though the URL is still the same

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I tried to loop over a list of URL to get the image URL of all the pages. However, when using loop, the request returns 400. When I tested individual URL, it works(200). Fail since the first call.

Tried adding time delay but still doesn't work.

```
f = open(url_file)

lineList = f.readlines()
print(lineList[0]) # Test
i = 1
for url in lineList:
    print(url) # Test -- the url is the same as lineList[0] above
    res = requests.get(url) # works when copied the printed url in but not as a variable
```

Expected 200 -- error gave 400

Comment: *"When I tested individual URL"* what does that mean, exactly?

Comment: Looks to me like you're adding a list of URLs. The first one in the file might be valid, but is (for example) the second? Are all the lines in the file a valid URL?

Comment: Could you post a sample of `lineList`?

Answer (score 2):

#### Explanation

If your `url_file` has newlines (`\n` character) as line separators, it **may** result in erratic response from the server. This is because `\n` is not automatically stripped from the end of each line by `f.readlines()`. Some servers will ignore this character in the URL and return `200 OK`, some will not.

For example:

```py
f = open(r"C:\data\1.txt")  # text file with newline as line separator
list_of_urls = f.readlines()
print(list_of_urls)
```

Outputs

```
['https://habr.com/en/users/\n', 'https://stackoverflow.com/users\n']
```

If you run `requests.get()` on these exact URLs above, you will receive `404` and `400` HTTP status codes respectively. Without `\n` at the end they are valid existent web pages - you can check it yourself.

You haven't noticed these extra `\n` in your code because you used `print()` on **each item** which does not show this symbol "explicitly" as `\n`.

#### How to fix

Use `splitlines()` instead of `readlines()` to get rid of `\n` at the end:

```py
import requests

with open(url_file) as f:
    list_of_urls = f.read().splitlines()  # read file without line delimiters

for url in list_of_urls:
    res = requests.get(url)
    print(res.status_code)
```

Comment: This worked for me I just needed to change #url = line to:
        url = line.replace("\n","")

Answer (score 0):

Use urllib2 and change adres of txtfile where webpages are stored:

example source of urls: http://mign.pl/ver.txt

```
import requests
import urllib.request as urllib2

response = urllib2.urlopen('http://mign.pl/ver.txt')
x=response.read().decode("utf-8")
d=x.split("\n")
print(d)

for u in d:
    res = requests.get(u)
    print(res.status_code)
```

output:

```
200
200
```

Answer (score 0):

another option using generator:
example source of urls: http://mign.pl/ver.txt

```
import requests
import urllib.request as urllib2

print(*(requests.get(u).status_code for u in urllib2.urlopen('http://mign.pl/ver.txt').read().decode("utf-8").split("\n")))
```

output:

`200 200`